# Connection timed out when calling java program from AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I'm trying to execute RUNJVA command on a jar file having http and getting connection timed out error.

When I execute same jar file from windows, it works fine and below is the output.

```
<CUSTOMER xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<ID>49</ID>
<FIRSTNAME>George</FIRSTNAME>
<LASTNAME>Fuller</LASTNAME>
<STREET>534 - 20th Ave.</STREET>
<CITY>Olten</CITY>
</CUSTOMER>
```

When i execute same jar file from AS400, below is the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ8dQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Could be due to invalid address

Have you tried pinging the server you are trying to connect to from your IBM i?

Or otherwise made sure that the server is reachable from the IBM i?

I've seen IBM i systems that couldn't connect to the internet.  Either because they are not configured properly (usually no DNS) or for security reasons.

To check DNS, do
GO CFGTCP
Option 12. Change TCP/IP domain information

DNS Servers are on the second page.